# Terraform returning the path of Azure Resource Group instead of ID

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-group

I'm using `Terraform` to manage my Infrastructure and `Terratest` for Testing.
In terraform, I have a module called `ResourceGroup` (located in the `Modules` folder)

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "azResourceGroup" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_region
  tags = var.tags
}
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.azResourceGroup.id
}
```

And I'm using this module in the `main.tf` to create an Azure Resource Group.

```
module "azResourceGroup" {
  source              = "./Modules/ResourceGroup"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags
}
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = "${module.azResourceGroup.resource_group_name}"
}
```

When I execute `terraform apply` the output of `main.tf` is returning the full path of the newly created Resource Group instead of its ID.

Here's the Output

```
Changes to Outputs:
  - resource_group_name = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-x/resourceGroups/rg-svf-nprd-test" -> null
```

Preferably, it should return only `rg-svf-nprd-test` (Id from output variable).

Am I missing anything here? Please help me with this.

Comment: That's what `id` attribute returns. Can you try to use `azurerm_resource_group.azResourceGroup.name`?

Comment: It'll not work.

Comment: Any reason why you have to have the name as an output?

Comment: @MarkoE Probably for reproducible testing in Terratest, but otherwise unsure how your comments are not the answer here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  Here main's output variable references the Module's output variable.

Comment: @Shrees It cannot display the name as there is only an `id` attribute exported. In other words, it cannot be done the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: @MarkoE Please let me know how to handle output variables via Modules? Because I need to check these with `Terratest`